# Flutter: White space coming while using BoxConstraints

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino, flutter-3.0, flutter-material

White space coming in horizontal view, while giving max width to Container with BoxConstraints.

Versions

Flutter: 3.3.0

Dart: 2.18.0

My code

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    decoration: ...,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Flexible(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Image.asset(
              'assets/logo/logo.png',
              width: 300,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          flex: 2,
          child: Card(
            shape: ...,
            elevation: 8.0,
            child: Container(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: 500,
              ),
              height: 400,
              child: ListView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
                children: [
                  Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ...
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Screen short:

Horizontal view, white space coming on right side

[image: Horizontal view]

Vertical view

[image: Vertical view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the outer `Container` width to the screen width wit `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` or even easier to `double.infinity`. It's going to be like the following:

```dart
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: ...,
        width: double.infinity,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
```

[image]

Comment: I don’t want to set infinity width. Want to set maximum width.

Comment: Infinity is going to be the maximum in Flutter. As you can see in the screenshot the `Container` is properly centered. If infinity wasn't the maximum you would not be able to see the centered `Container` as it is going to be out of sight.

Comment: I want to set custom max width, not infinity.

Comment: Are you talking about the outer `Container` or the inner one with `BoxConstraints` applied? The change is in the outer one, not the inner one. The constraint should still be there in the inner `Container`.

Comment: The inner one, basically i dont want my card to stretch too much in big screen.

Comment: Just change the outer one like I said. Don’t change the inner one.